# How to pass value of array from one Activity to other?

Tags: android, arrays, parsing, android-fragments

I am building an android application where an user select their favorite stuff.

The name of stuff is added in an array when user clicks on the stuff's image.

Now I want to know how can I parse the value of that array to any fragment and show it in my spinner list.

For example: user select Mobile and tablet by clicking on respective images then these values added in to an array name 'stuffarray' now I want to pass this array to my fragment on an 'submitted' button and when I click on an spinner of my fragment it Should have mobile and tablet value in there list.

Here is my code for stuff selection :
I am building an android application where an user select their favorite stuff.

The name of stuff is added in an array when user clicks on the stuff's image.

Now I want to know how can I parse the value of that array to any fragment and show it in my spinner list.

For example: user select Mobile and tablet by clicking on respective images then these values added in to an array name 'stuffarray' now I want to pass this array to my fragment on an 'submitted' button and when I click on an spinner of my fragment it Should have mobile and tablet value in there list.

Here is my code for stuff selection :

```
submite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextscreen);      
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent innext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivitytabnew.class);

    startActivity(innext);              

});
img1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


 img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mobile);   
 img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     isClicked1=!isClicked1;
        if (isClicked1) {
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mobile);
            start();
            stuff1 = "mobile";

               myList.add(stuff1);



        }else {
            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mobile);
            myList.remove(sport1);
            //sport1 = "";  
            txt1.setText("");
        }
}
});

img2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
img2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet);
img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    isClicked2=!isClicked2;
    if (isClicked2) {
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tablet);
        start();
        stuff2 = "tablet";
       myList.add(stuff2);
    }else {
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tablet);
       // sport2 = "";
        myList.remove(sport2);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: u can make the arraylist as static.

Comment: No I do not want my array list to be static

Comment: use the concept of singleton class.4

Comment: use the concept of singleton class.

Comment: How can I use singleton class for array parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also set the value before you open it.

**First activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, YourOtherClass.class );
int[] myArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; 
YourOtherClass.array = myArray;
startActivity( intent );
```

**Second activity**

```
public static int[] array;
```

Where `this` is your activity.

Comment: @thanks can you please tell me now how can I add this array value to my spinner

Comment: That is a complete different story. Search for Spinner Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use putExtra():

```
int helloworld = 100;

Intent intent = new Intent( this, Class2.class );
intent.putExtra( "myInt", helloworld );
startActivity( intent );
```

then in your next activity use getExtra()
see [documentation for intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

```
int passedInt = getIntent().getExtras().getInt( "myInt" );
```

Comment: I am done as your ans my code - Intent innext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivitytabnew.class);
    innext.putExtra(mysportlist, myList);
    startActivity(innext);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mysportlist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: but when i am toasting the value for checking it is null

Comment: You need to get the value from the other class as well. `array[0] = getIntent().getExtras().getInt( "int" );`